# use axios in getStaticProps in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, next.js

i have a next project.in this project i used axios for send and recieved request data.
but i have a problem when i use axios in getStaticProps function i get an error in my index.js page

this is my index.js

```js
 import axios from "axios";

const Home = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return <div>d</div>;
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');

    return {
        props: {
            data: res
        }
    };
}


export default Home;
```

and this is my index.js page in my browser
[image]

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it worked

```js
 try {
        const result = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
        const data = result.data;
        return {
            props: {
                data: data
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `res.data`. Next time, I recommend to use `console.log(res)` and see the object that you receive

Answer (score 0):

Add **JSON.stringify** when calling an asynchronous function that returns an object.

Try modifying the `getStaticProps` function like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    const stringRes = JSON.stringify(res);
    return {
        props: {
            data: stringRes
        }
    };
}
```

**OR**

Use `.text()` to convert the response data to text like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').lean();
   const textRes = await res.text();
    return {
        props: {
            data: textRes 
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It did not work and about solution2 i recieved this error lean is not a function

Comment: error changed and new error is lean is not a function

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify(res)`?

Comment: I updated my second method, can you give it a try?

Comment: no but this is worked                                                                                                 await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/init').data

Comment: i forgot use data in response